# JavaScript : how to reduce a group of arrays using index?

Tags: javascript

I have a question

I have an array group like this :

```
myArray = { tab1 : [], tab2 : [], tab3 : [], tab4 : [] }
```

I want to always keep my first tab (tab1) and to keep an additionnal tab using an index (which value is between 2 and 4)

For example : if my index value is 2, I want to keep the tab2 and obtain this :

```
myArray = { tab1 : [], tab2 : [] }
```

Thanks

Comment: Enumerated properties are usually a sign that something is at it's core a list; like an array. If you'd use an array, you could use Array methods like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of good answers already posted so just gonna post an alternative if interested.

Inside the function you create an array with the `tab1` string and the other key you want to keep received as parameter for your function.

1. Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to list all properties in the `Myarray` object
2. [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to select keys that are present in the allowed list, using
3. [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to make sure they are present
4. [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to build a new object with only the allowed properties.

```js
const myArray = {
  tab1: [],
  tab2: [],
  tab3: [],
  tab4: []
}

function keepTab(array, tab) {
  let allowed = ['tab1'];
  let addKey = 'tab' + tab;
  allowed.push(addKey);
  const filtered = Object.keys(array)
    .filter(key => allowed.includes(key))
    .reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = array[key];
      return obj;
    }, {});

  return filtered;
}

console.log(keepTab(myArray, 2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to do something like this

```
Object.entries(myArray).reduce((acc, [key, value], index) => {
  // Check if it is the first element or the one to keep
  if (!index || index === indexToKeep) {
    acc[key] = value;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Here `Object.entries(myArray)` will transform your object into an 2d array of key / value

```
[
  ['tab1', [/* Value of myArray.tab1 */]], 
  ['tab2', [/* Value of myArray.tab2 */]], 
  // etc...
]
```

`reduce` will then iterate on each index of the 2d array and will allow us to build an object for which a new value will be return after each iteration.

`acc` is the current value of the object, `[key, value]` are the key and the value of the current iteration.

Comment: This will have problems if the keys are added to the object out of order.

Comment: I used the index because he wanted to, but he can also use the wanted key

Answer (score 1):

To get `tab1`, and some other tab specified by an index...

```js
let someIndex = 3;
let myArray = { tab1 : ['1'], tab2 : ['2'], tab3 : ['3'], tab4 : ['4'] }

let key = `tab${someIndex}`;

let reducedArray = { tab1: myArray.tab1, [key]: myArray[key] };
console.log(reducedArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add some boundry-checking logic.

```js
const allTabs = { tab1: [1], tab2: [2], tab3: [3], tab4: [4] };

const getTabs = (id, { tab1, ...tabs }) => {
  if (id < 2 || id > Object.keys(tabs).length + 1) {
    throw Error(`Tab ID of ${id} out of bounds!`);
  }
  const tabKey = `tab${id}`;
  return { tab1, [tabKey]: tabs[tabKey] };
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(getTabs(2, allTabs))); // { tab1 : [1], tab2 : [2] }
console.log(JSON.stringify(getTabs(3, allTabs))); // { tab1 : [1], tab3 : [3] }
console.log(JSON.stringify(getTabs(4, allTabs))); // { tab1 : [1], tab4 : [4] }

// Lower-bound
try { getTabs(1, allTabs); }
catch (e) { console.log(e.message); } // Tab ID of 1 out of bounds!

// Upper-bound
try { getTabs(5, allTabs); }
catch (e) { console.log(e.message); } // Tab ID of 5 out of bounds!
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```